# Using a macro to generate a Julia command to be executed in the REPL

Tags: julia

I am a Julia (and stackoverflow) newbie but am trying unsuccessfully to simplify a function call.
I need to define calls to create many instances of 30 different structs, each having a different set of properties.
The code below works but will force the user to use exactly the same string twice, as in:
         EV_668876 = newEV("EV_668876", "test EV")
This is a pain and likely to cause errors.
I have written a macro to generate the command but can't get REPL to execute the command.
Here is the code (sorry for its length).

```
 mutable struct EV
    label::FixedLabel
    id::FixedId
    name::String
    designAuth::Ident
    descripn::String
    timestamp::String
    priority::Int16
     assoc_EO::Ident   # this needs a new Set of EOstructs, to be defined
    origin_OV::Ident    # similar Set of OVstructs
    OV_destination::Ident    # this needs a new OVstruct, to be defined
    underRespOf::Ident
    underAuthOf::Ident
end

function newEV(id::String, name::String)
    trylabel = String(split(id,['-',':','_'])[1]) # Note that split() yields a SubString(String)
    if trylabel !== "EV"       # ! => not
        throw(DomainError("This id $id is not an EV, try again"))
    end
    labelFixed = FixedLabel(trylabel) 
    registerId(id) # registers id if OK 
    idFixed = FixedId(id)
    # ident = newId(id,name)
    new = EV(labelFixed,idFixed,name,anon_anon,"","",0,anon_anon,anon_anon,anon_anon,anon_anon,anon_anon)
end

EV_668876 = newEV("EV_668876", "test EV") # runs OK and produces
#=
This runs OK and produces
EV_668876 registered OK
EV(FixedLabel("EV"), FixedId("EV_668876"), "test EV", Ident(FixedLabel("PPR"), FixedId("PPR-2"), "Anon_Anon"), "", "", 0, Ident(FixedLabel("PPR"), FixedId("PPR-2"), "Anon_Anon"), Ident(FixedLabel("PPR"), FixedId("PPR-2"), "Anon_Anon"), Ident(FixedLabel("PPR"), FixedId("PPR-2"), "Anon_Anon"), Ident(FixedLabel("PPR"), FixedId("PPR-2"), "Anon_Anon"), Ident(FixedLabel("PPR"), FixedId("PPR-2"), "Anon_Anon"))
#=

# === Attempting to use a macro to simplify the newEV() function ===
macro create(id,name)
    label = "EV"
     return :(println($id," = new",$label,"(\"",$id,"\", \"",$name,"\")"))
end
@create("EV_97234894","new test")
#=
This   generates    
EV_97234894 = newEV("EV_97234894", "new test")   which is what I want 
but returns a type nothing – is that why REPL doesn't execute the result?
#=
# ==============================================
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand (and I'm not sure what the printing does in your example), you want a macro that expands

```
@create <id> <name>
```

to

```
<id> = newEV("<id>", name)
```

The following will achieve that:

```
julia> macro create(id::Symbol, name)
           :($(esc(id)) = newEV($(String(id)), $name))
       end
@create (macro with 1 method)

julia> @macroexpand @create EV_234324 "new test"
:(EV_234324 = (Main.newEV)("EV_234324", "new test"))
```

`@macroexpand` is for debugging, since I didn't copy your code. It simply gets the expression that results from a macro call.

`esc`aping is necessary here, since you want the identifier given by the symbol `id` to end up being defined in the calling scope.

Comment: That did exactly what I needed when I removed the @macroexpand (I need to read the Julia documentation to understand "esc")

Comment: Of course you need to remove that :) Its purpose is just to show you what the actual macro call will result in.